# Add Unique field in User FOS

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOS and sf 3.3

I create My User class that extend FOS

In my User Class I have a field Unique

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="myField", type="string", length=42, nullable=true, unique=true)
 */
protected $myField;
```

This field is visible in profile/edit, after authentication.
If user inserts `myField` and `myField` is not Unique in my Database, I have 500 error, I'd like to have an error like `'The myfield is already used.'` in top of my form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique entity constraint in your extended entity class, see [UniqueEntity constaraint](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)